# Create mysql event inside concat with variables

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need to create an event to a user that is stored in a variable, but i'm getting this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE DEFINER= 'event_handler'@'localhost' EVENT store_failed_logi' at line 1

I'm trying:

```
SET @username := 'event_handler';
SET @store_failed_login_attempts_event := concat("
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER= '",@username ,"'@'localhost' EVENT store_failed_login_attempts
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 second
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log_messages (ip, created_at,username)
SELECT 
    ipaddresses as ip, times as created_at, user_host as username FROM login_attempts.general_log_federated
WHERE
    command_type = 'Connect'
GROUP BY login_attempts.general_log_federated.user_host;
END //
DELIMITER ;
");

PREPARE stmt10 FROM @store_failed_login_attempts_event; 
EXECUTE stmt10; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt10;
```

if i execute the RAW result of the concat string, it works, but it doesn't work with the prepare statements.

Comment: (#1) DELIMITER is client command, not SQL statement. (#2) CREATE EVENT statements are not allowed in dynamic SQL. [SQL Syntax Permitted in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted)

Comment: @Akina is there a workaround for an event with variables without using the DELIMITER?

Comment: Event procedure cannot be created using dynamic SQL. Dixi.

Answer (score 0):

After running your script I got the same error. I got it fixed after removing double qoutes after concat function.

```
SET @username := 'event_handler';
SET @store_failed_login_attempts_event := concat(
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER= '",@username ,"'@'localhost' EVENT store_failed_login_attempts
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 second
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE DO BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log_messages (ip, created_at,username)
SELECT 
    ipaddresses as ip, times as created_at, user_host as username FROM login_attempts.general_log_federated
WHERE
    command_type = 'Connect'
GROUP BY login_attempts.general_log_federated.user_host;
END //
DELIMITER ;);

PREPARE stmt10 FROM @store_failed_login_attempts_event; 
EXECUTE stmt10; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt10;
```

Then run the script it will create event for you.

Comment: *Then run the script it will create event for you.* Have you tried this in practice?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, after running your script, i getting an new error that says "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1". I think removing the quotes is not the solution.